# Ordering of basis elements of a Lie-group representations tensor product

Tags: group-theory, permutations, tensor-products, tensors

Let's consider a Lie Group $G$ and its complex representation  $\textbf{N}$. Let's consider the decomposition
$$
\textbf{N}\otimes\bar{\textbf{N}} = \bigoplus_J \textbf{r}_J 
$$
where $\textbf{r}_J$ are the irreducible representations (For simplicity, I consider the case with no degenerate subspaces).

First question:
Is $ \bar{\textbf{N}}\otimes\textbf{N} =  \textbf{N}\otimes\bar{\textbf{N}}$ always true? Since the decomposition is the same, I would say yes. If I take $|a\rangle \in \textbf{N}$ and $|\bar{b}\rangle \in \bar{N}$, is the following equation true?
$$|a\bar{b}\rangle = |\bar{b}a\rangle\tag2$$

I have some doubts about this last equality. Infact, If I use the Clebsh-Gordan decomposition for the group $G$
$$
|a\bar{b}\rangle = \sum_{I,i}C^{a\bar{b}}_{I,i}|I,i\rangle, \tag 3
$$
I can use $(3)$ to derive
$$
\langle c\bar{d}\mid a\bar{b}\rangle = \delta_{ac}\delta_{\bar{b}\bar{d}} = \sum_{I,i}(C^{c\bar{d}}_{I,i})^*C^{a\bar{b}}_{I,i}. \tag 4
$$
But, If I assume $(2)$ is true, I can write 
$$
\langle c\bar{d}\mid a\bar{b}\rangle = \langle \bar{d}c\mid a\bar{b}\rangle = \delta_{a\bar{d}}\delta_{c\bar{b}}= \delta_{ac}\delta_{\bar{b}\bar{d}}$$
which is obviously incorrect. I think $(2)$ is not true but I am not convinced.

Second question: If I consider $$ \textbf{N}\otimes\bar{\textbf{N}} \otimes \textbf{N}\otimes\bar{\textbf{N}} = \textbf{N}\otimes\textbf{N}\otimes\bar{\textbf{N}}\otimes\bar{\textbf{N}}$$
can I write
$$
|a\rangle\otimes |\bar{b}\rangle\otimes|c\rangle\otimes|\bar{d}\rangle =|a\rangle\otimes |c\rangle\otimes|\bar{b}\rangle\otimes|\bar{d}\rangle 
$$
and so
$$
|a\bar{b}\rangle\otimes|c\bar{d}\rangle  = |ac\rangle\otimes|\bar{b}\bar{d}\rangle  ?
$$
I am making a lot of confusion with the order of indices.

Comment: I changed $\displaystyle \textbf{N}\otimes\bar{\textbf{N}} = \oplus_J \textbf{r}_J$ to $\displaystyle \textbf{N}\otimes\bar{\textbf{N}} = \bigoplus_J \textbf{r}_J$.  Also I added some instances of \tag and \mid. Where $\langle c\bar{d} | a\bar{b}\rangle$ appeared I put $\langle c\bar{d}\mid a\bar{b}\rangle$.  With \mid, the space to the left and right depends on the context.  \tag formats the equation numbers. $\qquad$